# Adding a background image to an <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a different background image to an `li` in jQuery.

```
if (item.ctotal != 0) {
    var list = '<li><a href="menu.html?idcat=' + item.id_cat + '">' + item.category_cat + '</a></li>'
} 
else if (item.dtotal != 0) {
    var list = '<li><a href="results.html?idcat=' + item.id_cat + '">' + item.category_cat + '</a></li>'
}

var pagePath = webserviceUrl + '/imageResize/dir:category,image:' + item.id_cat + '.jpg,width:' + width + ',idhos:' + idhos;
var $img = $("<img />").attr('src', pagePath);
$($img).load(function() {
    $(list).css('background-image', 'url(' + $img.attr("src") + ')')($img);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, but that didnt work.

Comment: Try this : `$(list).css('background', 'url(' + pagePath + ')');`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error :

what is `($img);`doing in  `$(list).css('background-image', 'url(' + $img.attr("src") + ')')($img);`

Comment: Yes, it is pointless. However, it won't generate an error. `$(jQobject)` returns `jQobject`.

Comment: I have just tried those and unfortunately neither are display the background image.